Issue with Redirect from 'www.bioscience.com.pk' to English Homepage in Joomla 5 Multilingual Setup
Hi Stack Overflow Community,
I'm running a Joomla 5-based multilingual website and facing an issue with redirection from the main domain (www.bioscience.com.pk) to the English version of the site (www.bioscience.com.pk/en/). Below are my current settings and the problem I am encountering:
Website Setup:
Homepage with 'language all':

Alias: home

English homepage:

Language: English
Alias: en

Urdu homepage:

Language: Urdu
Alias: ur

Problem:
When users visit www.bioscience.com.pk, they are automatically redirected to the English version at www.bioscience.com.pk/en/. However, I would like visitors who access www.bioscience.com.pk to land on the homepage set to 'language all' without any redirection.
My Current Language Filter Settings:

Language Selection for new Visitors: Site language
Automatic Language Change: No
Item Associations: Yes
x-default Language: Default frontend language
Remove URL Language Code: No

What I Want:
I don't want the site to redirect users from www.bioscience.com.pk to www.bioscience.com.pk/en/. Instead, I'd like them to stay on the www.bioscience.com.pk homepage (set to 'language all').
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!
